# How to use condition on relationship in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 4 models "User","Team","Company" and "TeamMember". In that I have define relationship as below.

User.rb

```
belongs_to :company
```

Team.rb

```
belongs_to :company
```

TeamMember.rb

```
belongs_to :team
belongs_to :user
```

Now I want to allow only those user as team member which are belongs to same company as team

e.g If a team belongs to company "Abc" then it should allow only those user as a team member which are belongs to same company "Abc".

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a [custom validator](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods) to the `TeamMember` model like this:

```
validate :ensure_user_and_team_companies_match

private

def ensure_user_and_team_companies_match
  unless user.company == team.company
    errors.add(:base, "User's and team's company don't match")
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks for answer but issue is it goes in condition and also allow to insert. Rather I want generate Exception, If I remove :base then it will raise an exception.

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand. This would not allow to create invalid records and simply use `create!` or `save!` instead of the version without the bang when you want an exception instead of an error message. Does that answer your comment? Otherwise can you please elaborate?

Comment: your code allow to create invalid records, If I remove :base then it will raise an exception but error message is "undefined method `User's and team's company don't match' for #<TeamMember:0x007fb225127be8>", but I simply want that don't allow to create invalid record and message would be "User's and team's company don't match".

Comment: If in Rails a validation fails, then the `save` or `create` method returns `false` and the record itself is not saved into the database. Using normal Rails conventions this means it is not possible that my code writes invalid code into the database. Can you please explain how your save the records (you might use a way that bypasses validations)? Btw, when you remove the `:base` part, the error message is about a syntax error, because the `add` method expects that argument indicating the target attribute for the error message.